# Formatting DateTime.ToShortTimeString() correctly on WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have times that I am printing as follows:

`dateTime.ToShortTimeString();`

This prints out something like "3:21 PM", even if the user's phone is set to display times as "15:21 PM". Is there a way I can make `dateTime` use some localization/formatting parameter to take this into account?

Comment: Did either @Claus or myself answer this question for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it as part of a Binding, you could use a `ValueConverter`. Just mind you there's a "bug" when formatting dates in a `ValueConverter`

I [wrote a blog post on the subject](http://windcape.posterous.com/datetime-formatting-in-a-valueconverter) with code samples on how to utilize it for in-XAML date formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) static class to get the current phone's settings. This class gives you a range of formatting options for date and time strings. Just tested it and it works fine.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FullDateTimePattern);
// output changes when I modify the phone settings
// 15 September 2011 17:01:57 
//  or
// 15 September 2011 05:01:57 PM
```

Cheers,
Al