# DateTime cannot resolve ToShortTimeString()

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a Windows phone app where I have been using the `ToShortTimeString` method on some `DateTime` attributes.

I am now using this code in a Windows 8 store app and getting errors as `ToShortTimeString` cannot be resolved.  When I check what is available on a `DateTime` object I see a smaller list of options available - clearly its a date but just a few missing options (one of which is '`ToShortTimeString`'.

Have I done something really dumb here?

Am I missing a namespace?  I am using 'system' although resharper is telling me that it is not required.

Comment: What is your code and what is the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ToShortTimeString` simply isn't supported in Windows 8 Store Apps. You can see that when you check the "Version Information" in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx). It doesn't mention Windows 8 Store Apps.

But that's not really a problem. You can easily create this method yourself:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string ToShortTimeString(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return dateTime.ToString("t", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the shortened string versions, just use "ToString" as specified here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.85).aspx

```
thisDate.ToString("t");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread:

[Windows Phone 7 DatetimeFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432968/formatting-datetime-toshorttimestring-correctly-on-wp7)

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FullDateTimePattern);
```

> output changes when I modify the phone settings

15 September 2011 17:01:57

//  or

15 September 2011 05:01:57 PM